# How do I instantiate a php class from a PDO outer join statement?

Tags: php, join, pdo, fetch

I am currently working on a small business management tool. I'm just going to call it a customer manager. I have classes created for customers, invoices, and payments. I want to be able to get a payment class object with PDO::fetchClass on results that contain fields from a left join. I tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM payments LEFT OUTER JOIN ON payments.invoiceno = invoices.id";
    $table = $this->getTableList("Payment", $sql);

public function getDbObjects($class, $sql = false)
{

    if(!$sql) {
        $table = strtolower($class).'s';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    }

    $stmnt = $this->_databaseConnection->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmnt->execute()) {
        $objects = array();
        while ($object = $stmnt->fetchObject($class)) {
            var_dump($object);
            $objects[] = $object;
        }

        return $objects;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I get a result set that contains all the values, so I added the fields from invoices to payments but when I call fetchclass on the result, the fields from payments are not set in the object returned. I have confirmed they are in the result set. Is this possible? I have found related questions but only to create 2 objects from a join, not 1 from a join.

Comment: What's the result of the var_dump?

Comment: The var_dump produced empty fields until I tried it on a test page. I neglected to post the getTableList function and I apologize for that. I copied the code in those getTableList and getDbObjects directly into the controller and made some changes and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by copying my function code directly into my controller class

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM payments LEFT OUTER JOIN invoices ON payments.invoiceno = invoices.id";
    //$table = $this->getTableList("Payment", $sql);
    $stmt = $this->_databaseConnection->query($sql);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $objects = array();
        while ($object = $stmt->fetchObject('Payment')) {

            $objects[] = $object;
        }


    }
    $table = $this->getTableList($objects);


 public function getTableList($results)
{
// Fetch all payments from database and store in array
 $results = $this->getDbObjects($objects);

    // Initialize variables
    $colNames = array(); $head = ""; $body = "";

    // Loop over results to create table data (td) string
    foreach ($results as $result) {

        // Fetch associative array from results
        $row = $result->getListRow();

        // Initialize table row string
        $tableRow = "<tr>";

        // Gather column names for table header
        if( empty($colNames) ) $colNames = array_keys($row);

        //loop over columns to create html table data string
        foreach ($row as $td) {

            // Populate table data
            $tableRow .= "<td>$td</td>";

        }

        // Close table row
        $tableRow .= "</tr>";

        // Add row to table body
        $body .= $tableRow;
    }

    // Gather table header column names
    foreach ($colNames as $colName) {
        $head .= "<th>$colName</th>";
    }

    // Construct table
    return "<table><thead><tr>".$head."</tr></thead><tbody>".$body."</tbody></table>";
}
```